# What happens to timed out message in Akka when using the ask pattern?

Tags: akka

If you use the ask pattern in akka and the message times out. Will the message stay in an actors mailbox or is it discarded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actor that received the message will continue to process it even after the future that is waiting for the response times out. When that actor finally finishes and tries to respond that response will most likely become a dead letter.